# Why in the proof of running time of Kruskal's algorithm, the max number of edge is smaller than the square of number of nodes?

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory, kruskals-algorithm

In the running time of Kruskal's algorithm, the time for sorting edges is mlogm when we use quick sort. But as descried in 'Algorithm Design', the max number of edges is smaller than the square of number of nodes, so sorting the edge costs at most mlogn time. I can't understand this statement as even in a complete graph, shouldn't the max number of edges be n(n-1)/2?

Comment: I don't understand your question. n(n-1)/2 *is* smaller than n², is it not?

Comment: Indeed n(n-1)/2 is smaller than n². But the book has such statements: 'Since we have at most one edge between any pair of nodes, we have m<= n².' It doesn't make sense, no? it should be n(n-1)/2.

Comment: In the asymptotic sense, n(n-1)/2 and n² are the same functions !

Comment: Would you feel better if the book said instead: "Since we have at most one edge between any pair of nodes, we have m <= n(n-1)/2 <= n²"?

Comment: Why doesn't it make sense? If m <= n(n-1)/2, then clearly m <= n². If you can prove what you want to prove using n² why go through the trouble of shlepping around the more complex expression n(n-1)/2?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're right in that a complete graph has *n(n-1)/2* edges. Since *n(n-1)/2 = n^2/2 - n/2 < n^2*, the statement you quote holds true.

If your source of confusion is "why did the author say less than *n<sup>2</sup>* instead of *n(n-1)/2*", then it's likely because *n<sup>2</sup>* is a simpler expression and a sufficient one to prove that paragraph is trying to say, namely that the cost of sorting is at most *m log n*.

If you prove that something holds whenever the number of edges is *<= n<sup>2</sup>*, then it will also hold in the real world, since the number of edges is *<=n/(n-1)/2 <= n<sup>2</sup>*.